# View обьекты android

Tags: java, android, view

Когда программно создаешь `View`, например `ImageView`, то когда вписываешь `LayoutParams` нужно ввести ширину и высоту. Но в комментариях написано, что вводится в `px`. А как вводить `dp`?

Answer (score 2):

Можно перевести `dp` в `px`

```
public static float convertDpToPixel(Context context, float dp){
    DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    return dp * ((float)metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
}
```

И обратно

```
public static float convertPixelsToDp(Context context, float px){
    DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    return px / ((float)metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
}
```

Comment: Круто. Я искал примерно такой метод а оказывается надо в вручную. Спасибо