# Как установить расстояние между кнопками программно в GridLayout

Tags: java, android, margin, grid-layout

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_random"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/marginBottomTop_button"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_button"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_button"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_button"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
        android:fontFamily="@font/brusdi"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_question"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_button"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_button"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
        android:fontFamily="@font/brusdi"/>




    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginBottomTop_button">

        <GridLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/tableGrid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

        </GridLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Java**

```
package com.example.examenatorproject;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.PrecomputedText;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.GridLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableGrid);
        gridLayout.removeAllViews();

        Button button = null;
        gridLayout.setColumnCount(3);
        gridLayout.setRowCount(5);


        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout
                .LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.leftMargin = 45;
        layoutParams.rightMargin = 45;
        layoutParams.topMargin = 45;
        layoutParams.bottomMargin = 45;

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                button = new Button(this);
                button.setId((5 * i) + 1 + j);
                button.setText(String.valueOf((5 * i) + 1 + j) );

                button.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                gridLayout.addView(button);

                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        int id = v.getId();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }});
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Проблем в том что расстояние так и не увеличиваются между кнопками, как это можно исправить ?

Comment: попробуйте button.setPadding

Comment: Так это внутренние отступы, а мне нужны внешние

Comment: разницы нет, вам нужно расстояние увеличить между кнопками

Comment: `button.setPadding()` тоже не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Протестировал, работает.

```
GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableGrid);
gridLayout.removeAllViews();

Button button = null;
gridLayout.setColumnCount(3);
gridLayout.setRowCount(5);


final int margin_px = 10;


for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        button = new Button(this);
        button.setId((5 * i) + 1 + j);
        button.setText(String.valueOf((5 * i) + 1 + j) );

        GridLayout.LayoutParams glp =  new GridLayout.LayoutParams( );
        glp.width = GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        glp.height = GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        glp.setGravity( Gravity.CENTER);
        glp.setMargins( margin_px, 0, margin_px, 0 );

        glp.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(i);
        glp.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(j);

        button.setLayoutParams( glp);
        gridLayout.addView(button, glp);
    }
}
```

Comment: стоит учесть, что маржины задаются именно в пикселях, 
а у вас они указаны, как фиксированное значение, то есть на разных разрешениях экранов они могут существенно отличаться. рекомендуется [рассчитывать этот параметр](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/821885/177345) преобразуя dp (фиксированное значение, например 8) в px на конкретном устройстве (первый метод в ответе)

Comment: или [такой способ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51625345/7566397) перевода dp из dimen-ресурса в пиксели